# local email send in osCommerce

Tags: email, oscommerce

I have install osCommerce and Xampp, I am using Mercury Mail for local emails.

Now, how can i configure email setup in osCommerce, so that emails will be send to customers.

I have tried. to change the configure email setup by giving as 
`superadmin@localhost.com` and `customer1@localhost.com` but emails are not sent in osCommerce system.

Where as i configure Thunderbird it perfectly working fine.

Do i need to change any other configuration files related to emails in osCommerce.

Comment: Did you ask your host if they've disabled `mail()` from your account?

Comment: @random I have not installed onto live Webserver, have installed over my localhost. So how can i send emails through mercury in osCommerce settings.

Answer (score 0):

Rafee, you need to go to your admin panel, which is probably located at http://www.yourdomain.com/catalog/admin or http://www.yourdomain.com/admin or whatever you named "admin".

From there, you can adjust your OSC settings -- including mail that gets sent to you and to your customers.  It doesn't matter what e-mail client you're using, whether it's MS Outlook or Mozilla, or whatever.  It's all configurable through your admin panel.

If you have OSC version 2.3, which you should have if you don't, then I'd recommend an addon such as [Contact Us Enhancement](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/8323) which is not only an enhancement for receiving e-mail, but also sending your customers the mail you're intending to send 'em (whether it's an invitation to create an account, a receipt, a thank you for the order, or whatever).

Comment: yourdomain.com is an actual live site. You should in future use **example.com** instead.